# Mysterious memory usage immediately after login

Tags: windows-10

I'm having a strange problem on a pretty new pc (Lenovo c940). Just after signing in, memory usage skyrockets to 12-13gb out of 16gb. There is no sign of any memory hogs in the process list or resmon, and I have disabled most programs from automatic startup. Anyone have any tips as to where to go next to figure out what is wrong?

[image: processes]
[image: performance]

[image: startup]
[image: resmon]

Comment: You have a pile of Chrome tabs open.  Close Chrome, restart, keep Chrome closed and check again. Chrome uses memory like this so that is normal for all those tabs

Comment: Have you got anything like SQL Server installed? These sorts of services tend to gobble up RAM.

Comment: Have any VMs running?

Comment: Click the reveal arrow beside  > Chrome & add up the figures for your 21 tabs, which are not included in the simple figure [769MB] for the global app.

Comment: thanks for the tips guys. It turned out I had a VM that was on pause, and after reboot it automatically started running again [face palm]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently VM's does not show in process list. I had an Hyper-v Ubuntu instance running in  the background.